# New constructs for link, vlink and alink?

Tags: html

I have this common statement in my code

```
<body link="#FFFF00" vlink="#FFFF00" alink="#FFFF00">
```

Web Expression 4 highlight the code with a message 'The World Wide Web Consortium now regards the attributes as outdated.  Newer constructs are recommended.'

Unfortunately it doesn't give me any more information.

What code do I need to make it up to date?

Comment: You need to use CSS. Please take a look at the following link for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't embed styling within the structure of HTML - that's why you are getting the message. It's been quite a while that a separation between the document structure and how it looks has been accepted as a good thing - style goes into CSS.

To resolve the issue, use CSS.

For links you should style the `a` element with the pseudo classes for `link`, `visited` and `active`:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The attributes still work the same way they used to. Replacing them with CSS would be trivial, but would not change anything (except in the relatively rare cases where CSS is disabled – then default link colors would be used).

Using CSS would be useful if you wanted to use different colors for different links on a page, for example.

The main problem with the code is not the way you set link colors but setting them to the same color and to a color that is not commonly recognized as indicating a link.